# Is it possible to scroll the ScrollView that has vertical LinearLayout that has several TextViews (variable number) to the beginning of some TextView?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I don't know if it's possible. I have a ScrollView, vertical LinearLayout child to it and I inflate programmatically array of TextViews on this vertical LinearLayout .

Now, let's say, I want to open this Activity with ScrollView scrolled to `textView[4]`
Is that is possible to acheive?

Comment: Just in case... Are you aware of ListView?

Comment: yes, it's an idea to make a book app with a ListView, I haven't thought of that. It's too late to remake it, but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following method:

```
scrollView.post(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CountDownTimer(1500, 20) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int) (textViewAbove.getBottom()-millisUntilFinished));
                }

               @Override
               public void onFinish() {                 
               }
            }.start();
        }
    }
);
```

Where `textViewAbove` is the `TextView` above the `textView[4]`, `textView[3]` in that case.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you be kind enough to explain why you have used CountDownTimer ?

Comment: It takes 1.5 seconds scrolling, so it has the effect of scrolling. The activity open in the normal position, and then scrolls to the position during 1.5 seconds, not just simple open the view on the position.

Comment: @giacomoni, So you're implying that while the activity starts, it would delay for 1.5 seconds taking its time to scroll to the selected position ?

Comment: Yes, it takes 1.5 seconds scrolling to the selected position